# convert object to json

Tags: html, json, angular

How do convert object to JSON and output it on html page?

```
public User:UserInfo=
  {
    firstName: "O",
    lastName: "K",
    email: "ol@op.com",
    country: "uk",
    avatarUrl: null,
    receiveNotifications: true
  }
```

Comment: If you don't care about the formatting {{User | json}} should work, otherwise give more details, please

Comment: @oleg Which version of angular is this?

Comment: @Abdel Angular2/4

Answer (score 1):

I wish you had given us a bit more detail in your question, but I will do my best here so bear with me! Let's say you have an object that looks like this

`a.component.ts`

```
public obj = {
     name: "Oleg",
     question: "convert object to json",
     description: "Some cool question about angular and JSON"
}
```

To present this data, your view would look like this

`a.component.html`

```
<h1> {{ obj.name }} </h1>
<h2> {{ obj.question }} </h2>
<p>  {{ obj.description }} </p>
```

Please pay attention to how my class member is set to public, this is important whenever you are going to create an [AoT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) build of the application.

If you are having trouble understanding, my simplified example. Check out this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytu1jj)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
let jsonStr=JSON.stringify(user).
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are coming from the jQuery world, but with angular.js things are getting much simpler, please check this jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/ASspB/1/

With angular.js you can attach events much, much simpler:

```
  <input type="button" ng-click="showJson()" value="Object To JSON" />
    and then in your controller:
         $scope.showJson = function() {
        $scope.json = angular.toJson($scope.user);
    }
```

In fact this could be done even easier with angular.js filters, check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/ASspB/2/ which has:

```
{{user | json}}
```

Comment: The OP is in Angular not AngularJS